# how to change current worksheet name based on cells from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rename a worksheet with the year and three-letter abbreviated month, which are selected from drop-down lists (data validation) in cells C40 and C38, located within the 'Control' worksheet.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsControl As Worksheet
    Dim newName As String
    Dim yearValue As String
    Dim monthValue As String
    
    ' Define the Control worksheet
    Set wsControl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
    
    ' Check if the change happened in Control worksheet and in cells C38 or C40
    If Not Intersect(Target, wsControl.Range("C38, C40")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the year value from cell C40 of Control worksheet
        yearValue = wsControl.Range("C40").Value
        ' Get the month value from cell C38 of Control worksheet
        monthValue = wsControl.Range("C38").Value
        
        ' Check if both year and month values are not empty
        If yearValue <> "" And monthValue <> "" Then
            ' Construct the new name with year and three-letter abbreviated month name
            newName = yearValue & " " & Mid(wsControl.Range("C38").Value, 1, 3)
            
            ' Rename the current sheet to the new name
            Me.Name = newName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue with this code is that it keeps getting stuck on the `If Not Intersect(Target, wsControl.Range("C38, C40")) Is Nothing Then` line.

If I remove this line along with it's respective `End If`, then the code runs but only when I press F2 anywhere in the current worksheet (which is not what I want). I need the current worksheet to change names every time I update cells C38 and C40 in the 'Control' worksheet.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: The worksheet containing this code is referenced with `Me` or `Target.Worksheet` i.e. if it's not worksheet `Control`, then there cannot be an intersection i.e. `Intersect` only works with ranges on the same worksheet.

Comment: @GeoffreyFernandez the code is supposed to run when I'm the 'Control' worksheet and change the other worksheet's name

Comment: The worksheet containing this code is referenced with `Me` or `Target.Worksheet` i.e. if it's not worksheet `Control`, then there cannot be an intersection i.e. `Intersect` only works with ranges on the same worksheet. Decide which worksheet you want to rename i.e. put the code in worksheet `Control` and use the code name of the worksheet you want to rename e.g. `Sheet2.Name = newName`. In the *Project Explorer*, the code name is the name not in parentheses while its (tab) name, the name you're trying to change, is in parentheses.

Comment: I did try putting this code on the control worksheet and it didn't get stuck at the IF statement line you mentioned.

Comment: @VBasic2008 okay, so put this code in the 'Control' worksheet, and not in the worksheet whose name I'm changing? The worksheet that changes names will need to constantly change names based on the drop down selection in the 'Control' worksheet

Comment: Yes. Now identify the code name of the sheet that you will be repeatedly renaming and use it to rename it. See details in my previous comment and use the code name (usually something like `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`...) to replace `TheSheet` with it in Tim Williams' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CodeName` of the sheet to be renamed to reference it from the "Control" sheet's `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim yearValue As String, monthValue As String
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C38, C40")) Is Nothing Then
        
        yearValue = Me.Range("C40").Value
        monthValue = Me.Range("C38").Value
        
        If yearValue <> "" And monthValue <> "" Then
            ' `TheSheet` is the CodeName of the sheet to be renamed
            TheSheet.Name = yearValue & " " & Left(monthValue, 3)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You can set the sheet's `CodeName` in the VB editor project explorer pane. `CodeName` is independent of the tab name.